# Use lists as keys in a map

Tags: dart

`print({[1,2]:3}[[1,2]])` prints `null`. This is obviously unexpected.

Is there a blessed workaround or do I have to create a new list-like-class/wrapper and give it a proper `operator==` and `hashCode`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lists in Dart do not have equality based on their elements.

You can use a `Map` with a custom equality function.
There is an equality on lists defined in `package:collection/equality.dart`, so you can do:

```dart
import "dart:collection";
import "package:collection/equality.dart";
main() {
  const eq = const ListEquality();
  var map = HashMap(equals: eq.equals, hashCode: eq.hash, isValidKey: eq.isValidKey);
  map[[1,2]] = 42;
  print(map[[1,2]]);
}
```

That still won't allow you to use a map literal, though.

Comment: I think I'm willing to sacrifice a bit of literal convenience. :-)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work as equals: isn't defined on map constructor anymore.

Comment: ACK. Switched to using `HashMap` constructor. Could also use `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue for this: http://dartbug.com/17963 and maybe http://dartbug.com/2217

Hashmap has a constructor that accepts functions to calculate equality and the hashCode:

```dart
HashMap({
    Function bool equals(K key1, K key2), 
    Function int hashCode(K key), 
    Function bool isValidKey(potentialKey)})
```

You should be aware that when you calculate the hashCode dependent on the elements contained in the list and you modify the list while it is contained in the map you won't find it anymore (like in your example)

Comment: Mm, thanks for the link(s). I'll additionally note that I'd totally missed this constructor: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-collection.HashMap#id_HashMap- and that I can just pass in some lambdas.

Comment: Didn't know that either.